# How to select every 4th element starting from 2?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select elements from a pattern like `2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22`?

I tried to write this `(2+(n-1)4)` but CSS allows `+` and `-` operators only?

```
.timeline__item-bg:nth-child(2+(n-1)4):before {
    content: '';
    left: 74%;
    top: 99%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(4deg);
    background: #60a8e2 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your selector to the following:

```
.timeline__item-bg:nth-child(4n+2):before {}
```

Here's a working example:

```css
.timeline__item-bg:nth-child(4n+2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">1</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">2</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">3</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">4</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">5</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">6</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">7</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">8</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">9</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">10</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">11</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">12</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">13</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">14</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">15</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">16</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">17</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">18</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">19</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">20</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">21</li>
  <li class="timeline__item-bg">22</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

- To select every 4th element use `:nth-child(4n)`
- Starting from 2nd element `:nth-child(4n + 2)`

**Working Examlpe:**

```css
ul li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
</ul>
```